# Proper way to guard function operations using Option[] arguments

Tags: scala, optional-parameters

I have code where a class can provide modified copies of itself, like so:

```
case class A(i: Int, s: String) {
  def foo(ii: Int): A = copy(i = ii)
  def bar(ss: String): A = copy(s = ss)
}
```

I want to create a function that takes some optional arguments and creates these modified copies using these arguments if they are defined:

```
def subA(a: A, oi: Option[Int] = None, os: Option[String] = None): A = {
  if (oi.isDefined && os.isDefined)
    a.foo(oi.get).bar(os.get)
  else if (oi.isDefined && !os.isDefined)
    a.foo(oi.get)
  else if (!oi.isDefined && os.isDefined)
    a.bar(os.get)
  else
    a
}
```

This is clearly not sustainable, as I add new optional arguments, I have to create cases for every combination of arguments...

I also cannot do:

```
a.foo(oi.getOrElse(a.i)).bar(os.getOrElse(a.s))
```

Because in my actual code, if `oi` or `os` is not provided, I should NOT run their associated `foo` and `bar` functions. In other words, I have no default arguments for `oi` and `os`, rather their existence defines whether I should run certain functions at all.

**Current solution**, extend the class:

```
implicit class A_extended(a: A) {
  def fooOption(oi: Option[Int]): A = if (oi.isDefined) a.foo(oi.get) else a
  def barOption(os: Option[String]): A = if (os.isDefined) a.bar(os.get) else a
}

def subA(a: A, oi: Option[Int] = None, os: Option[String] = None): A = {
  a.fooOption(oi).barOption(os)
}
```

But this problem comes up often and it's a bit tedious to do this constantly, is there something like:

```
// oi: Option[Int], foo: Int => A
oi.ifDefinedThen(a.foo(_), a) // returns a.foo(oi.get) if oi is not None, else just a
```

Or should I just extend `Option` to provide this functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `fold` on option `final def fold[B](ifEmpty: => B)(f: A => B): B`

```
def subA(a: A, oi: Option[Int] = None, os: Option[String] = None): A = {
       val oia = oi.fold(a)(a.foo)
       os.fold(oia)(oia.bar)
}
```

*Scala REPL*

```
scala> def subA(a: A, oi: Option[Int] = None, os: Option[String] = None): A = {
   val oia = oi.fold(a)(a.foo)
   os.fold(oia)(oia.bar)
  }
defined function subA

scala> subA(A(1, "bow"), Some(2), Some("cow"))
res10: A = A(2, "cow")
```

or

Use pattern matching to deal with options elegantly. Create a tuple of options and then use pattern matching to extract the inner values

```
val a = Some(1)

val b = Some("some string")

(a, b) match {

 case (Some(x), Some(y)) =>

 case (Some(x), _) =>

 case (_, Some(y)) =>

 case (_, _) =>

}
```

Comment: This still requires enumerating out all combinations of `a` and `b`, which gets really ugly when I have many `Option` arguments.

Comment: Yay, I used to wonder why `Option` was iterable, this is yet another great reason for it to be.

Comment: @spiffman using simple map and flatMap composition . edited the answer

Comment: @spiffman oi.map(a.foo).flatMap(a => os.map(a.bar)).getOrElse(a)

Comment: The `map` / `flatMap` solution is incorrect unfortunately, try `subA(new A(5, "five"), None, Some("six"))`. If the first option is `None` then the output doesn't get chained to the second option.

Answer (score 0):

Well... You can use reflection to create arbitrary `copiers` and even `updaters` for your case classes.

The difference is that an `updater` updates the `case class instance` and the `copier` create a new copy with updated fields.

An implementation of an `updater` can be done as below,

```
import scala.language.existentials
import scala.reflect.runtime.{universe => ru}

def copyInstance[C: scala.reflect.ClassTag](instance: C, mapOfUpdates: Map[String, T forSome {type T}]): C = {
  val runtimeMirror = ru.runtimeMirror(instance.getClass.getClassLoader)
  val instanceMirror = runtimeMirror.reflect(instance)
  val tpe = instanceMirror.symbol.toType

  val copyMethod = tpe.decl(ru.TermName("copy")).asMethod
  val copyMethodInstance = instanceMirror.reflectMethod(copyMethod)

  val updates = tpe.members
    .filter(member => member.asTerm.isCaseAccessor && member.asTerm.isMethod)
    .map(member => {
      val term = member.asTerm
      //check if we need to update it or use the instance value
      val updatedValue = mapOfUpdates.getOrElse(
        key = term.name.toString,
        default = instanceMirror.reflectField(term).get
      )
      updatedValue
    }).toSeq.reverse

  val copyOfInstance = copyMethodInstance(updates: _*).asInstanceOf[C]
  copyOfInstance
}

def updateInstance[C: scala.reflect.ClassTag](instance: C, mapOfUpdates: Map[String, T forSome {type T}]): C = {
  val runtimeMirror = ru.runtimeMirror(instance.getClass.getClassLoader)
  val instanceMirror = runtimeMirror.reflect(instance)
  val tpe = instanceMirror.symbol.toType

  tpe.members.foreach(member => {
    val term = member.asTerm
    term.isCaseAccessor && term.isMethod match {
      case true =>
        // it is a case class accessor, check if we need to update it
        mapOfUpdates.get(term.name.toString).foreach(updatedValue => {
          val fieldMirror = instanceMirror.reflectField(term.accessed.asTerm)
          // filed mirrors can even update immutable fields !!
          fieldMirror.set(updatedValue)
        })
      case false => // Not a case class accessor, do nothing
    }
  })

  instance
}
```

And since you wanted to use `Option`s to copy, here is your define once and use with all case classes `copyUsingOptions`

```
def copyUsingOptions[C: scala.reflect.ClassTag](instance: C, listOfUpdateOptions: List[Option[T forSome {type T}]]): C = {
  val runtimeMirror = ru.runtimeMirror(instance.getClass.getClassLoader)
  val instanceMirror = runtimeMirror.reflect(instance)
  val tpe = instanceMirror.symbol.toType

  val copyMethod = tpe.decl(ru.TermName("copy")).asMethod
  val copyMethodInstance = instanceMirror.reflectMethod(copyMethod)

  val updates = tpe.members.toSeq
    .filter(member => member.asTerm.isCaseAccessor && member.asTerm.isMethod)
    .reverse
    .zipWithIndex
    .map({ case (member, index) =>
      listOfUpdateOptions(index).getOrElse(instanceMirror.reflectField(member.asTerm).get)
    })

  val copyOfInstance = copyMethodInstance(updates: _*).asInstanceOf[C]
  copyOfInstance
}
```

Now you can use these updateInstance or copyInstance to update or copy instances of any case classes,

```
case class Demo(id: Int, name: String, alliance: Option[String], power: Double, lat: Double, long: Double)
// defined class Demo

val d1 = Demo(1, "player_1", None, 15.5, 78.404, 71.404)
// d1: Demo = Demo(1,player_1,None,15.5,78.404,71.404)

val d1WithAlliance = copyInstance(d1, Map("alliance" -> Some("Empires")))
// d1WithAlliance: Demo = Demo(1,player_1,Some(Empires),15.5,78.404,71.404)

val d2 = copyInstance(d1, Map("id" -> 2, "name" -> "player_2"))
d2: Demo = Demo(2,player_2,None,15.5,78.404,71.404)

val d3 = copyWithOptions(
  d1, List(Some(3),
  Some("player_3"), Some(Some("Vikings")), None, None, None)
)
// d3: Demo = Demo(3,player_3,Some(Vikings),15.5,78.404,71.404)


// Or you can update instance using updateInstance

val d4 = updateInstance(d1, Map("id" -> 4, "name" -> "player_4"))
// d4: Demo = Demo(4,player_4,None,15.5,78.404,71.404)

d1
// d1: Demo = Demo(4,player_4,None,15.5,78.404,71.404)
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with my actual question, but wow, this is cool! My worry with something like `updateInstance` is that it changes the value of an immutable `val`, rendering it mutable.

Comment: I thought that you wanted a generic copier for case classes and were trying to get it done using `Option`s. Aso, If you do not need to update then you can just use `copyInstance` which reflects on the instace to capture its copy method and then uses it to create a copy with your updates fields.

Comment: The copy functions were just to illustrate the problem of using multiple `Option` arguments to guard whether or not some functions are executed. Either way, I appreciate the submission, a lot of the reflection API documentation is dense, I learned more about reflection by reading your code :)

Comment: Yup... your question looks pretty different from what I answered. Hope this answer helps some-one looking for such solution.

Comment: You should submit it to StackOverflow Documentation, there is currently next to nothing in the Scala Reflection page: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/scala/5824/reflection

Answer (score 0):

Another option (no pun intended, heh) would be to have `foo` and `bar` themselves take and fold over `Option`s:

```
case class A(i: Int, s: String) {
  def foo(optI: Option[Int]): A =
    optI.fold(this)(ii => copy(i = ii))

  def bar(optS: Option[String]): A =
    optS.fold(this)(ss => copy(s = ss))
}
```

Then, `subA` can be minimal:

```
object A {
  def subA(
    a: A,
    optI: Option[Int] = None,
    optS: Option[String] = None): A =
    a foo optI bar optS
}
```

You can also overload `foo` and `bar` to take plain `Int` and `String` as well if you have to maintain the API; in that case make the `Option`-taking methods call out to their corresponding non-`Option`-taking ones.